# I put some code of ads and AdMob but cant watch them

Tags: android, admob, ads

I am creating an app and want to add some Google Ads to the main page. I followed all the steps that Google says and don't have any warnings or error, but when I run the app, there isn't any ads.

This is the MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FragmentTabHost tabHost;
    private AdView mAdView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //adds

        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");

        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
```

This is the xml code of the mainActivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="35dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/mix">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/natacion"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg_rounded_corners"
        android:onClick="lanzarNatacion"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="Natacion" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/carrera"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="lanzarCarrera"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg_rounded_corners"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="Carrera" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the mainifest code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="soloviev.perez.vicente.ritmos">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_mi_icono_"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_mi_icono_"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".carrera" android:label="Calculadora ritmo de carrera" />
        <activity android:name=".natacion" android:label="Calculadora ritmo de natacion" />
        <activity android:name=".error" android:label="Error" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="ca-app-pub-4666536989991556~5464124026"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And I added all dependencies and repositories I had to add.

When I run just appear a label which says "Test Ad", but should appear something more.

The codes that i am using are the example codes that Google provides.

Thanks

Comment: check out logcat, there will be "ad failed to load 0" like message.

Comment: 02-05 11:12:55.080 21698-21767/---ritmos E/GooglePlayServicesUtil: The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.

Comment: 02-05 11:12:56.991 21698-21814/----.ritmos E/chromium: [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(264)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_SUCCESS

Comment: 02-05 11:12:56.991 21698-21814/---.ritmos E/chromium: [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(264)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_SUCCESS

Comment: pls post your build.gradle n log snap

Comment: Do you mead build.gradle?

Comment: You have taken `LinearLayout` then Why you use `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` params in <AdView> and If you are getting output then you should put screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

**please add net work permission in manifests**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

**change your code**

```
   mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

**with**

```
   mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView)
   AdRequest  adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build()
   mAdView .loadAd(adRequest )
```

**update**

log the error code

```
 mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

@Override
public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
   Log.d("Error code",errorCode.toString());
}
}
```

and check the error code here

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest#ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR

**Update**

in your gradle

```
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
```

Add end of your build.gradle(Module:APP)

```
 repositories {
 maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
google()
jcenter()
}
```

Comment: ok  vps please add net work permission in manifests      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: @vps You are saying that you have completed all the steps then why are you doing these steps one by one.

Comment: Use Relative layout instead of Linear layout

Answer (score 0):

try to update ads dependency

```
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0'
```